# Why is there a "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error when I apply my function to elements of a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to apply this function

```
def run():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input
```

to each element of this list of lists `liste = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]`.

Each element (starting from the first one) should be replaced by the user provided input `user_input`.

(Note, I want to change my existing list `liste`; I don't want to create a new one.)

So I tried to apply my function `run` using `map` in the list comprehension

```
liste = [x for x in map(run(),liste)]
```

But that statement results in the error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` by default receives a one param function (your `run` function receives no params). So change the `map` function to be:

```
liste = [x for x in map(lambda x: run(),liste)]
```

Or, change your `run` function to receive one parameter:

```
def run(x):
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input


liste = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

print([x for x in map(run, liste)])
```

**Keep in mind that `map` receives function, and not function invokation like you did.** The reason you got `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` is because you passed string value to map (`run` call returns string value) and not a function (`callable`)